# Vuforia plugin disappears on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, download, sdk, vuforia, download-manager

On my Mac, I noticed every time I open my AR project which uses Vuforia, the Vuforia plugin disappears and I have to go to the unity download page and redownload the Vuforia sdk. Any suggestions on why this is happening or has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm kind of new to Mac and I copied the unity app into the applications folder and then when I imported the Vuforia package it imported it to the original location of the Unity app, so when I open it from the original location it worked and when I opened it in the app location Vuforia didn't work